# Image in circle not completely visible

Tags: css, svg

I styled a cricle around an svg icon, but the icon is cut off on the top.

```css
.transport-circle {
  border: 3px solid #30574b;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px;
  fill: #30574b;
}
```

```html
<img class="transport-circle style-svg" src="https://wordpress-175698-743047.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/train.svg" alt="Train" width="100" height="100" />
```

Any idea how I can get the train icon fully visible?

Comment: It would be better to wrap the image in a div and then apply the circle styling to the div rather than the image.

Comment: Alternatively you could add some white space around the actual svg image to prevent it being cut off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can avoid the image being cut off when you apply border radius to the image, unless there is more white space around the actual svg image.

Alternatively you can add the circle styling to a wrapper div.

```css
.transport-circle {
  border: 3px solid #30574b;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 10px;
  fill: #30574b;
}
.transport-circle img {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="transport-circle style-svg">
<img src="https://wordpress-175698-743047.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/train.svg" alt="Train" width="100" height="100" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion. Both answers are working well. Eventually, I also changed the white space for some other icons with http://vectorpaint.yaks.co.nz/. This solved the problem too!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the icon as a background to avoid this issue:

```css
.transport-circle {
  border: 3px solid #30574b;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  background-origin:content-box;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="transport-circle style-svg" style="background-image:url(https://wordpress-175698-743047.cloudwaysapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/train.svg)" alt="Train" ></div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion. Both answers are working well. Eventually, I also changed the white space for some other icons with http://vectorpaint.yaks.co.nz/. This solved the problem too!